# How to work out what font an application is using?

Tags: .net, wpf, fonts

We are writing a DLL that adds functionality to an existing program written in Visual Studio 2010. It hooks into the existing application to load the DLL and represent its window as a tab in the main application.

I would like the tab to blend in with the existing application, but nowhere is it stated what font the application uses. We do not have the source code to the application.

How would I find this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tool such as [WPF Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) will allow you to examine all properties (including font family) for any visual element in a WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

Use [What The Font](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). You upload an image of your font and it will tell you likely fonts used.

Comment: I have tried this before but it doesn't match well, and since the font is on the system (installed) it should be one of them. I could try guessing (based on the installation date of the folders the application was created in, but can't find an exact match to that date).